# Specific Java EJB constraint violation error. Why?

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, bean-validation

I receive this error:

```
    javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation
failed for classes [EntityBeans.PwVersions] during update time for groups 
[javax.validation.groups.Default, ] List of constraint violations:
[ ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='size must be between 0 and 45', 
propertyPath=directory, rootBeanClass=class EntityBeans.PwVersions, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Size.message}'} ]
```

at runtime and am frustrated. The problems occurs when I try to cast my query result as a PwVersions object. I need to use the below line of code (or an equivalent) so I would like to know what I would have to change elsewhere (aside from altering the database) to get this to work? Perhaps there is a way to alter the constraint being violated (I am unfamiliar with handling constraints in Java)
(major/minor are both correct)

```
PwVersions pwv= (PwVersions)em.createQuery("select pwv from PwVersions pwv where 
major= :major and minor = :minor").getSingleResult();
```

THANK YOU

Comment: Show the PwVersions entity please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The validation exception is most probably thrown by this annotation:

```
@javax.validation.constraints.Size(min = 0, max = 45)
```

placed in front of a property of the class `EntityBeans.PwVersions`. To get rid of it, either adjust the length of the field(s) in the db table, or adjust the [Size](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html) annotation itself in order to match the max size of the db field (or remove the annotation if you don't need it at all).

The EJB exception is simply catching the validation exception and rethrowing it, because your code snippet is placed in an EJB.

Comment: Yes! I just figured that out and also, in the database, the column is of the type: VARCHAR2(45 BYTE)
Thanx!